# conditional attribute with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, attributes, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

I am looking to add a *required* attribute to one of my input with thymeleaf depending on a radio button.

My code is at the moment:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <fieldset class="col-md-6">
        <legend class="control-label init-font-size">
            <span th:text="#{myLabel}"></span>
        </legend>
        <label th:with="label_key='radio.'+${item}+'.label'" class="radio-inline required" th:id="'lbl_' + test + ${iteration.index}" th:for="'input_' + test + ${iteration.index}" th:each="item, iteration : ${ { 'yes', 'no' } }" >
            <input type="radio" required="required" th:id="'input_' + test + ${iteration.index}" th:field="*{test}" th:value="${item}"/>
            <span th:text="#{${label_key}}"></span>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="form-group row classTestInfos">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label" th:for="testInfos">
            <span th:text="#{test.label}"></span>
            <a role="button" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" th:attr="'data-target'='#help' + testInfos" class="btn btn-help collapsed" th:title="#{testInfos.title}">
                <span class="blank sr-only" th:text="#{testfInfos.title}"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="text-danger" aria-hidden="true" th:attr="'data-error-required'=#{testInfos.empty}, 'data-error-format'=#{testInfos.format}"></span>
        </label>
        <div>
            <textarea  id="testInfos" maxlength="400" class="form-control" th:field="*{testInfos}" aria-invalid="false"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do so that when 'yes' is checked on the radio button, the textarea will be required, if not it won't.

Comment: you need to add this control by javascript, and when a radio button is selected, add/remove the attribute required from the textarea

Comment: @cralfaro thank you for your answer, that is what i was thinking first, and that is what im going to do.